# AngularJS $filter not working in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

/Hello.

```
.directive('rnDatatable', function($filter) { //Таблица

return {

    scope : {
        ngTablefields : "=",
        ngTabledata : "="
    },
    restrict: 'AEC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.ngOrderb = function(fld) {
             scope.OrderRev=!scope.OrderRev
            scope.ngTabledata = $filter('orderBy')(scope.ngTabledata, fld,scope.OrderRev);
        }
    },          

    template: 
            '<table class="table table-striped">'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td  ng-repeat="fields in  ngTablefields">'+
            '<span class="text-primary pointer" ng-click="ngOrderb({fld:fields.colvalue})">   {{fields.colname}}   </span> </td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr ng-repeat="row in ngTabledata"  class="animate-if">'+
            '<td ng-repeat="fields in ngTablefields">'+
            '<span class="text-default "> {{row[fields.colvalue]}}</span>'+
            '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '</table>'  



};
```

});

I have an error on `$filter('orderBy')`

TypeError: object is not a function

- at Array. (/js/angular.js:15550:24)
- at comparator (/js/angular.js:15559:36)
- at /js/angular.js:15566:34
- at Array.sort (native)
- at /js/angular.js:15555:22
- at Scope.scope.ngOrderb (/js/controller.js:371:43)
- at /js/angular.js:10797:21
- at /js/angular-touch.js:472:9
- at Scope.$eval (/js/angular.js:12699:28)
- at Scope.$apply (/js/angular.js:12797:23)

Could you please explain me why?

update:  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LY8HxCAgOAEExp4NSz7F?p=info)

Comment: could you include an example for ngTablefields? This would help much to answer your question.

Comment: <rn-Datatable ng-Tablefields="psptablechngfields" ng-Tabledata="histpaspchanges"  ></rn-Datatable>

Comment: [{"colname":"Дата изменения", "colvalue":"EdDateTime", "type":"date"},
{"colname":"Пользователь БД", "colvalue":"EdDBOperator", "type":"string"},
{"colname":"Оператор", "colvalue":"EdWSOperator", "type":"string"},
{"colname":"АРМ", "colvalue":"EdApplicationTitle", "type":"string"},
{"colname":"Рабочая станция", "colvalue":"EdWorkstation", "type":"string"},
{"colname":"Состояние", "colvalue":"FName", "type":"string"}]

Comment: could you also include an exampe for `ngTabledata`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LY8HxCAgOAEExp4NSz7F?p=info

Comment: thx Bixi for help formalize. i'm new here and I have difficulty with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isthe `ng-click` directive in your template. The solution is quite simple:

```
<span class="text-primary pointer" ng-click="ngOrderb(fields.colvalue)">
```

Your example in the plunkr works when you change that argument to `fields.colvalue`.

Comment: thx. i found another way. $filter('orderBy')(scope.ngTabledata, fld.fld,scope.OrderRev);